# Changing name of image - PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rename

I get a permission error while trying to rename the name of image files in a folder. The code is:

```
import PIL
import os

path = r"C:\Users\hjh\Pictures\Logging 16.04"
os.chdir(path)


for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".JPG"):
        #print(os.path.join(path, filename))
        imgname=filename
    
        image=PIL.Image.open(imgname)
    
        EXIF_data = image._getexif()
    
      
        datetime = EXIF_data.get(36867)
        datetime = datetime.replace(":","")
    
        os.rename(imgname,datetime)
    

        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Does anyone see where the problem lies?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the file path. therefore the operating system tries to write the files to where you are running the python code from.
you should use something along these lines:

```
datetime = EXIF_data.get(36867)
datetime = datetime.replace(":","")
os.rename(imgname,"{}.JPG".format(os.path.join(path , datetime)))
```

also, keep your files closed on any other application (e.g. picture viewer)